# Jquery function pause a video ID

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

Im building a site which loads in different videos in different divs from a central navigation.

The problem i am having is that after i navigate to another page, the div with the video playing continues to play off in the background.

I am wanting to create a function that pauses the video element when i navigate away.

This is what i have so far:

```
$("a").click(function () {
$('#videoId').pause()
});
```

I know the trigger is working as i can replace the pause with remove and it removes the div, but i want it to pause.

Answer (score 1):

`$` returns a `jQuery` object. If you get to the raw DOM element, you can use [its `pause` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#media-elements). To get a DOM element from a jQuery object, you can use [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get). So:

```
$("#videoId").get(0).pause();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. It dosnt seem to be working for me though and im not sure what im missing. Also, i am loading the div with the video in it from an external html file with ajax, could that be an issue?